# Material Date Picker title is out of place

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, material-components-android

I'm having this weird issue when using MaterialDatePicker. While it *works*, the title and current date are not displaying as they should.

Any ideas on what is happening?

I'm using Material Components library version 1.2.0

This is the result I'm getting:

[image]

I'm using the default style for the MaterialDatePicker and did not overload anything related to it, to the best of my knowledge.

This is the theme I'm using for this activity:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Any hints or directions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Which theme are you using in the app?

Comment: Hi @GabrieleMariotti, added the info on the description, let me know if you are suspicious of anything that I can try it on the app

Answer (score 2):

My problem was using FragmentActivity. I switched to AppCompatActivity and it worked for me.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31717055)

Answer (score 0):

try this code:-

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{
        TextView textView;
        Button txt_open_date_picker;
        int yy,mm,dd;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            textView = findViewById(R.id.text);
            txt_open_date_picker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.txt_open_date_picker);
    
            txt_open_date_picker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                            MainActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.this,
                            Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR),
                            Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH),
                            Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    
                    datePickerDialog.show();
                }
            });
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            String date = dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year;
            textView.setText(date);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, the issue only happens when using MaterialDatePicker, not DatePickerDialog

Answer (score 0):

You can align the selection text like this:

```
<style name="MyCustomMaterialDatePicker" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
    <item name="materialCalendarHeaderSelection">@style/MaterialCalendar.HeaderSelection</item>
</style>


  <style name="MaterialCalendar.HeaderSelection" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.HeaderSelection">
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">start|bottom</item>
</style>
```

And then on Koltin

```
MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker().setTheme(R.style.MyCustomMaterialDatePicker)
```